# Number of elements in the given construction of set cover

Tags: combinatorics, finite-fields

Consider the following construction that is used to form an instance of a set cover, taken from Vijay Vazirani (2003) *Approximation Algorithms*, $\S13.1.1$

Let $n=2^{k} - 1$, where $k$ is a positive integer. For $1 \le i \le n$, we use $\mathbf{i}$ to denote the $k$-bit number $i$ as a $k$-dimensional vector over [GF(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2)).

Also define set $S_i = \{ e_j \vert \mathbf{i} \cdot \mathbf{j} = 1\}$, where $\mathbf{i} \cdot \mathbf{j}$ denotes the inner product of these two vectors. Finally, let $\mathcal{S} = \{S_1, \ldots ,S_n\}$.

The author claims that it is easy to check that each set $S_i$ contains $2^{k − 1} = (n + 1) / 2$ elements, and each element is contained in $(n + 1) / 2$ sets.

And indeed it is easy to *check* these claims, yet a formal proof does not appear anywhere. Am I missing something trivial here or is there a nuanced proof of this claim?

Comment: Something does not add up, Is it supposed to be $n=2^k-1$ rather than $n=2k-1$? If so, then the first claim follows from the fact that $\mathbf{j}\mapsto \mathbf{i}\cdot\mathbf{j}$ is a surjective homomorphism from $GF(2)^n$ to $GF(2)$, and the second claim follows essentially be reversing the roles of $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$. By the way, what is the difference between a verification and a formal proof? I would use the word *verification* to mean that I checked the veracity of the claims when, for example $k=5$ and $i=23$, but it is unclear what you want.

Comment: I am awfully sorry, I did not even take a second look at that. You're right, $n=2^k-1$ and the first claim is $2^{k-1} = (n+1)/2$, and I can see how that would result from (the now evident) surjective homomorphism.

Comment: Like you, I would also use the word verification to mean checking the correctness of a claim, in this case by fixing $i$ and $k$. I guess more than a proof, what was needed here was the introduction of a missing idea that would help make sense of the claim(s), the proof would have followed quite naturally.

Comment: No problem! The main thing is that your problem was sorted out. Feel free to write an answer now that you know how it goes. Your call, of course.